# How to draw a Segmet line using MouseMove in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, line, mousemove

When I triggered MouseUp the drawn lined is continuing ...and don't disrupt

### mousemove event

```
private void Wind_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isMouseDown)
    {
        x2 = e.GetPosition(this).X;
        y2 = e.GetPosition(this).Y;
        if (again)
        {
            grid.Children.Clear();
        }
        Line line = new Line();
        line.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        line.X1 = x1;
        line.Y1 = y1;
        line.X2 = x2;
        line.Y2 = y2;
        grid.Children.Add(line);
        again = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever reset isMouseDown to false? As a note, it would be far more efficient to add points to a Polyline, instead of adding single Line elements to a Canvas.

Comment: For a better practice you should use the `CaptureMouse();` on _MouseDownEvent_, `IsMouseCaptured` on _MouseMove_ and `ReleaseMouseCapture()` on _MouseUp_ instead of a `isMouseDown` variable. Way easier and more robust when leaving/entering the control.

Comment: You know inkcanvas exists, right?  If you wanted curved lines then using ink and converting that to a polyline would give better results. I use ink for drawing terrain such as woods, roads etc in our map editor.  I also have an alternative  "snap line" process for drawing straight lines.